# What speech service does Orca Screen Reader use?

Tags: programming, orca

What speech service does Orca Screen Reader use?

Is there any API to access it from an application? Like:

```
function talk (text) { /* convert text to speech */ }
```

...or maybe via bash commands?

```
talk "Hello World"
```

Being a sofware developer I am interested in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default orca uses `espeak` as a TTS-engine. You can use `espeak` directly from terminal or script:

```
espeak "hello world"
```

To use it with a different language use

```
espeak --voices
```

to list the available voices, and then use the `-v` option to specify the voice, e.g. for your language:

```
espeak -vro "some romanian slang here"
```